# How to reload a page if 504 gateway timeout error appears anytime in an automated process on Python? Selenium related

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, exception, signals, http-status-code-504

I'm trying to automate a process within a website using `Selenium` on `Python3.x`, and sometimes the `Error 504 Gateway time-out` appears as shown below:

[image: error504]

I would like to know if there's a way I can tell my program to reload the page (after several seconds have passed) in case this error appears **anytime during the automated the process**, as **it is kind of random** but after 1 or 2 refreses everything is back to normal.

Any ideas?

Comment: When this occurs, does the URL changes to something specific?

Comment: In my case it does not @Prophet